# OrderBy difference between two nullable dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two nullable dates and I'd want to OrderBy amount of days between them if two of them have value, else throw them at the beginning or at the end

Here's my current idea that translates to SQL fine, but how can I improve it?

```
public static IQueryable<Order> ApplyOrderBy(this IQueryable<Order> input, Rules rules)
{
    switch (rules.OrderBy)
    {
        case "Date":
        {
            input = rules.Direction == "asc" 
            ? 
            input.OrderBy
            (
                x =>
                (x.SentDate == null ? new DateTime(1990,1,1).Date : x.SentDate.Value.Date)
                -
                (x.ReceivedDate == null ? new DateTime.Now(1990,1,1).Date : x.ReceivedDate.Value.Date)
            )
            :
            input.OrderByDescending
            (
                x =>
                (x.SentDate == null ? new DateTime(2990,1,1).Date : x.SentDate.Value.Date)
                -
                (x.ReceivedDate == null ? new DateTime.Now(1990,1,1).Date : x.ReceivedDate.Value.Date)
            );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, why is there a case statement if you only have one available path? And secondly the idea behind the ternary operator is to make an if statement in one line to simplify readability and usually assign a value to a variable, in this case I would argue that it is having the opposite effect. Being honest it took me a while to understand the code.

Comment: Use .GetValueOrDefault() rather than a ternary?

Comment: @nalnpir I didnt want to show whole switch cuz that's pointless. I also agree that readability ain't great here